# Auto sync the data into drafts without pressing any button like as in sending Gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, gmail-api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to design a tool for a website which auto syncs the data into drafts without pressing any button like as in sending Gmail and when the user exits the page, all the data he has entered prior is retained and he can edit and send the form any time he wants. I currently work on Angular and Node. I tried searching everywhere about how Gmail sync works but they went in vain.I also noticed that LinkedIn has this feature of auto syncing. Adding a draft button is not an option to save data into database is not an option here.
I also noticed that many questions in Stackoverflow are based on submitting a form without showing submit button **but specifically my question is not that**.
I need to store the user entered data in a form in my database as soon as he started typing something and finally there is a submit button which sends the form results like send button in Gmail.
The main concern here is not to lose data already entered with a poor internet connection or mistakenly closed tab and start again from beginning.
While writing this question, I also noticed that there is also draft syncing in stackoverflow which stores my already typed question.

[An Example from stackoverflow itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNcnr.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in localstorage or something https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

This persists the data on the client side through page navigations and doesn't require internet connection.